# Python - how can I dynamically remove a method from a class -- i.e. opposite of setattr

Tags: python, setattr

I don't know if I have a good design here, but I have a class that is derived from unittest.TestCase and the way I have it set up, my code will dynamically inject a bunch of `test_*` methods into the class before invoking unittest to run through it.  I use `setattr` for this.  This has been working well, but now I have a situation in which I want to remove the methods I previously injected and inject a new set of methods.  How can I remove all the methods in a class whose names match the pattern `test_*`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's called `delattr` and is documented [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#delattr).

Comment: @JasonSperske: Not if you have to delete an attribute whose name is computed programmatically.  You can only use `del` to delete a name you can literally type in the source code.

Comment: @JasonSperske -- the title says "opposite of setattr" implying that OP knows the method name as a string...

Comment: The common usage for me is `delattr(type(obj), 'test_foo')` (for testing purposes only). A method cannot be unbound from a Class object, but only from the entire class(which affects all the objects)

Comment: @BryceGuinta however, isn't it strange, that I can do st. like `foo.quack = lambda: "Quack"; print (foo.quack())` where *quack* was not defined so far for *foo*?

Comment: @lef  A method defined in a class is bound to the instance upon creation. You're setting a new attribute on an object which happens to be a function where the object happens to be an instance of a class.

A bound method (which is defined in the class) implicitly passes the instance to the class's method (usually called self). Your function however does not do that

Comment: But delattr delete attributes not methods... Trying to delete mathods will give you an attribute error

Comment: @GM: Methods are attributes.

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> class Foo:
    def func(self):
        pass
...     
>>> dir(Foo)
['__doc__', '__module__', 'func']
>>> del Foo.func
>>> dir(Foo)
['__doc__', '__module__']
```

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to the previous answers: If the method to be deleted is re-implemented, you'd have to delete the subclass and parent class methods, both:

```
class A:
    def method(self): 
        print("TestA")

class B(A):
    def method(self):
        A.method(self)
        print("TestB")

instance = B()
instance.method() # will call B.method()
del B.method
instance.method() # will now call A.method()
del A.method
instance.method() # will now raise AttributeError
```

(Or use `delattr` of @BrenBarn's answer)

Answer (score 1):

`delattr()` is what you want. Loop through `vars()` of the class and test for attribute names starting with `"test_"`. E.g.,

```
@classmethod
def remove_test_methods(cls):
    for name in list(vars(cls)):
        if name.startswith("test_") and callable(getattr(cls, name)):
            delattr(cls, name)
```

I'd advise against using `dir()`, as this will show you names from your parent classes as well, so not all the names you get from `dir()` may defined on the class you're targeting.

Comment: This looks good, however I got `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`

Comment: Oh yeah, `vars()` is a dictionary even though I'm just using the keys. Let me fix that...

Comment: Yeah, as I say, you don't want `dir()` as it will find stuff in parent classes.